# Overrides color of a control but not work in design mode

Tags: c#, user-interface

I coded a control which inherits Control class. The code likes

```
class MyControl : Control {      
    private SolidBrush foreColor = new SolidBrush();    
    public override Color ForeColor {    
        get { return foreColor.Color; }    
        set { foreColor.Color = value; }      
    }
}
```

It looks okay but when I assign the forecolor in design mode, it always show the default color in runtime. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITED**

I was confused with the similar problem, and find out that Design mode does not generate `Property = Value` in auto generated codes. Please check the auto generated code in `FormName.Designer.cs`.

If you have the same situation with me, please try

```
set
{
    foreColor.Color = value;
    base.ForeColor = value;
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11269217)

Comment: I think this could solve his / her problem since I have the same problem before. Please refer to http://jccsharp.blogspot.tw/2012/05/troubleshooting-user-control-overrides.html

Comment: Correct.  The designer will only write the property value if it is different from the default value.  As posted in the OP, it has no way to see it is different, it only looks at the base.ForeColor property value.  Using the [DefaultValue] attribute is another solution, but awkward.

Comment: @Hans: Well, while true as such, in the context of the question this is off, imo. The OP only uses a __name__ that sounds like forecolor but really uses/confuses it as/with a brush. He also expects a control to show text and finally does not provide a default values (other than Color.Empty). Also his problem is not showing the default but what he claims sets in the Designer. Which is nothing obviously, as the code doesn't even compile..

Comment: I don't wanna change it's base color, please see my edited question.

Comment: @JeremySimpson I know, but please take a try, and also reference to Hans Passant's comment.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up brushes and colors.

This will work as expected:

```
class MyControl : Control
{      
    private Color foreColor = SystemColors.ControlText;

    public override Color ForeColor
    {
        get { return foreColor; }
        set { foreColor = value; }
    }

}
```

Note that a `Control` as such will not **show** much, expcially no `Text`, so you may want to test it with a `Label` or any other control that has a **visible** `Text`property instead: `class MyLabel : Label` or, of course by setting not the `ForeColor` but the `BackColor`..

Using the automatic property syntax works just as well as long as you don't want to use the private filed to set **default** colors, as the generated field will not be accessible! (It will not use the one you have declared for obvious reasons..)

```
class MyLabel : Label 
{      
    public override Color ForeColor { get; set; }
}
```

Also make sure to **unselect** the control in the designer to see the color you set!

**Update**  I you really want to subclss `Control` setting the `ForeColor` makes no sense unless you help ypur class to show the `Text`, as `Control` is one of the many controls that do not show their `Text` property, like `Panel` `PictureBox` etc..

Here is an example:

```
class MyControl0 : Control
{
    private SolidBrush foreColor = new SolidBrush(SystemColors.ControlText);
    public override Color ForeColor
    {
        get { return foreColor.Color; }
        set { foreColor.Color = value; }
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
         base.OnPaint(e);

        TextFormatFlags flags = TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter |
                                TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter ;
        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, Text, Font, ClientRectangle, 
                              ForeColor, flags);
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited my question, and I want to change the color of the SolidBrush directly.

Comment: `SolidBrush` needs an argument in its constructor. So you can write `private SolidBrush foreColor = new SolidBrush(SystemColors.ControlText);`. This will sort of 'work'. Except, as I have said repeatedly, a blank __Control will not show its Text__ so setting its `ForeColor` makes little sense, until you add an `OnPaint` that does!! Why do you inherit from `Control` ?? It is the base of all controls and as such rather stupid. Or maybe you mean the `BackColor`???